# LWC not creating a record in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

I have the below js that is supposed to take the parameter from a screen and create a new credit object record. Everything is working except for the creation of the credit_object record. I am not receiving any error messages either. Any thoughts.

```js
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import pushDataFromDAndB from '@salesforce/apex/DNBBlock_Push.pushDataFromDAndB'

import CREDIT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Name';
import ACC_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Account_Name__c';
import DUNS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.DUNS_Number__c';
//import EMPLOYEES_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Employees__c';
//import FAILURE_SCORE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Failure_Score__c';
//import  MAX_CREDIT_LIMIT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Maximum_Credit_Limit__c';
//import PRIMARY_ADRRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Primary_Address__c';
//import PRIMARY_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Primary_Name__c';
//import TOTAL_CURR_LIAB_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Total_Current_Liabilities__c';
//import REGISTRATION_NUMBER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Registration_Number__c';
//import TOTAL_EXPERIENCES_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_Object__c.Total_Expereinces_Count__c';

//import more fields here whic you want to populate

export default class DAndBCheck_DataItem extends LightningElement {
    @api item;
    @api accid;
    regisnumber;
    organizationData;

    connectedCallback(){
        if(this.item.organization.registrationNumbers.length > 0){
            this.regisnumber = this.item.organization.registrationNumbers[0].registrationNumber;
        }
       
    }

    handleCreateCredit(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showspinner'));
        pushDataFromDAndB({DUNS : this.item.organization.duns})
        .then(result => {
            this.organizationData = result;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.organizationData));
            this.createCreditRecord();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showspinner'));
        })
    }

    createCreditRecord(){
        console.log('##DUNS$$$', JSON.stringify(this.item.organization.duns));
        const fields = {};
        fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = 'Testing';
        fields[ACC_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.accid;
        field [DUNS_FIELD.fieldApiName]=this.duns;
        //populate the above impoted fields here like we are doing just above

        let recordInput = { apiName: CREDIT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields }
        createRecord(recordInput)
        .then(result => {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showspinner'));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('ERROR');
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showspinner'));
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo when building `fields`.

```js
fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = 'Testing';
fields[ACC_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.accid;

//typo below on field - should be fields
field [DUNS_FIELD.fieldApiName]=this.duns;
```

The typo causes the code to not reach the wire (which is why you get no response - success or error).